# How to check the contents of postgres

Tags: thegraph

I'm running tests with Matchstick and my save() calls don't seem to be working (I set up my tests by saving some entities, but then my application code doesn't see them when it goes to load).

Is there any way to check the current state of the backend and see what's in there? Mainly just trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you just have to read the docs
https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developer/matchstick/

logStore()